# How can I join two columns from a single table when their foreign keys reference the same table?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two tables, one called `locations` and one called `work_packages`, pictured here:

[image: table]

I want to be able to query a row in the `work_packages` table and get  the columns associated with the foreign keys `location_a` and `location_z`. Everything I have tried has resulted in errors.

My current model looks like this:

[image: currentmodel]

And this is what I've been working with as a query:

[image: query]

Executing the query:
[image: executing]

Now, I've tried a few variations on the model and query but nothing I've done has worked. I get errors such as 'Column has no property Mapper' and many different shades of 'AmbiguousForeignKeyError'.

The error messages indicate that I need to be more specific about how the two tables should be joined, but I'm at a loss when it comes to doing that the correct way.

Could really use some guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the primaryjoin in the relationship? E.g.:

```
a_side_name = relationship('locations', primaryjoin='locations.uid==work_packages.location_a')
z_side_name = relationship('locations', primaryjoin='locations.uid==work_packages.location_z')
```